# Importing tables from external database in Symfony2 with doctrine

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I have a Symfony2 project with its own database, and now I want to connect to another database (another project) so I can modify some tables.

I created the new connection in `config_dev.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     localhost
                dbname:   database1
                user:     root
                password: 
            buv:
                driver:   pdo_mysql
                host:     localhost
                dbname:   database2
                user:     root
                password:
```

I tried to import the schema with the following command:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --em=buv MyBundle yml
```

> [Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\SchemaException]
>       Index '' does not exist on table 'old_table'

But some of the tables in database2 have no PKs! And the full import dosn't work. But I only want to import two tables, so I tried:

```
$ php app/console doctrine:mapping:import --em=buv --filter="tablename" MyBundle yml
```

But I'm getting the same error, seems that --filter isn't working.

The documentation in the console command `doctrine:mapping:import` only says to put the entity name in the filter option. But I don't have an entity yet.

Comment: Try doctrine.dbal.schema_filter: ~^(?!table1|table2)~ . Works for me on symfony 4.4.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I get you correctly, you want to import your existing database?

What I do is:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/App/MyBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

Then do a selective convert to annotation:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppMyBundle annotation --filter="users_table"
```

If you wanted to yml, change annotation to yml.

warning: when you import to annotation or yml, it will delete your current entity file.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, the first command you suggest doesn't seem to work since one of my tables doesn't have a PK. How does this solve it?

Comment: Try writing filter argument in camel case starting with big letter, ie: 


    php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AppMyBundle yml --filter="UsersTable"

Comment: When I have this problem, the --filter seems not to be applied. Can't solve it yet.

Answer (score 15):

It is a requirement for Doctrine to **have an identifier/primary key**.
Take a look at this page: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifiers-primary-keys

But there **is a way to generate mappings and entities from tables that do not have a primary key**. A table with no primary key is an unusual and bad database design but such a scenario exists in case of legacy databases.

**Solution**:
**Note**: All references below refer to Doctrine 2.0 
1. Find the file **DatabaseDriver.php** (in Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/Driver/DatabaseDriver.php)
2. Find the method **reverseEngineerMappingFromDatabase**. Modify the code as stated below. 
The original code is:

```
private function reverseEngineerMappingFromDatabase()
    {
        if ($this->tables !== null) {
            return;
        }

        $tables = array();

        foreach ($this->_sm->listTableNames() as $tableName) {
            $tables[$tableName] = $this->_sm->listTableDetails($tableName);
        }

        $this->tables = $this->manyToManyTables = $this->classToTableNames = array();
        foreach ($tables as $tableName => $table) {
            /* @var $table \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table */
            if ($this->_sm->getDatabasePlatform()->supportsForeignKeyConstraints()) {
                $foreignKeys = $table->getForeignKeys();
            } else {
                $foreignKeys = array();
            }

            $allForeignKeyColumns = array();
            foreach ($foreignKeys as $foreignKey) {
                $allForeignKeyColumns = array_merge($allForeignKeyColumns, $foreignKey->getLocalColumns());
            }

            if ( ! $table->hasPrimaryKey()) {
                throw new MappingException(
                    "Table " . $table->getName() . " has no primary key. Doctrine does not ".
                    "support reverse engineering from tables that don't have a primary key."
                );
            }

            $pkColumns = $table->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns();
            sort($pkColumns);
            sort($allForeignKeyColumns);

            if ($pkColumns == $allForeignKeyColumns && count($foreignKeys) == 2) {
                $this->manyToManyTables[$tableName] = $table;
            } else {
                // lower-casing is necessary because of Oracle Uppercase Tablenames,
                // assumption is lower-case + underscore separated.
                $className = $this->getClassNameForTable($tableName);
                $this->tables[$tableName] = $table;
                $this->classToTableNames[$className] = $tableName;
            }
        }
    }
```

The modified code is:

```
private function reverseEngineerMappingFromDatabase()
    {
        if ($this->tables !== null) {
            return;
        }

        $tables = array();

        foreach ($this->_sm->listTableNames() as $tableName) {
            $tables[$tableName] = $this->_sm->listTableDetails($tableName);
        }

        $this->tables = $this->manyToManyTables = $this->classToTableNames = array();
        foreach ($tables as $tableName => $table) {
            /* @var $table \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Table */
            if ($this->_sm->getDatabasePlatform()->supportsForeignKeyConstraints()) {
                $foreignKeys = $table->getForeignKeys();
            } else {
                $foreignKeys = array();
            }

            $allForeignKeyColumns = array();
            foreach ($foreignKeys as $foreignKey) {
                $allForeignKeyColumns = array_merge($allForeignKeyColumns, $foreignKey->getLocalColumns());
            }

            $pkColumns=array();
            if ($table->hasPrimaryKey()) {
                $pkColumns = $table->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns();
                sort($pkColumns);
            }

            sort($allForeignKeyColumns);

            if ($pkColumns == $allForeignKeyColumns && count($foreignKeys) == 2) {
                $this->manyToManyTables[$tableName] = $table;
            } else {
                // lower-casing is necessary because of Oracle Uppercase Tablenames,
                // assumption is lower-case + underscore separated.
                $className = $this->getClassNameForTable($tableName);
                $this->tables[$tableName] = $table;
                $this->classToTableNames[$className] = $tableName;
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Find the method **loadMetadataForClass** in the same file. Modify the code as stated below. 
Find the code stated below:

```
try {
   $primaryKeyColumns = $this->tables[$tableName]->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns();
} catch(SchemaException $e) {
    $primaryKeyColumns = array();
}
```

Modify it like this:

```
try {
     $primaryKeyColumns = ($this->tables[$tableName]->hasPrimaryKey())?$this->tables[$tableName]->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns():array();
} catch(SchemaException $e) {
     $primaryKeyColumns = array();
}
```

The above solution creates mappings(xml/yml/annotation) even for tables that don't have a primary key.

Comment: im my file there is no such line exist which u have mention in `loadMetadataForClass` method

Comment: This applies to doctrine 2.x versions

Comment: `private function getTablePrimaryKeys(Table $table)
        {
            try {
                $primaryKeyColumns = ($this->tables[$table->getName()]->hasPrimaryKey())?$this->tables[$table->getName()]->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns():array();
            } catch(SchemaException $e) {
                $primaryKeyColumns = array();
            }

    return array();
}`

Comment: Here is the suggested change from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15766666/1183444 in patch form- https://github.com/albertvolkman/doctrine2/compare/override-primary-key-req.patch

Comment: private function getTablePrimaryKeys(Table $table)
    {
        try {
            return ($table->hasPrimaryKey()?$table->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns():array());
        } catch(SchemaException $e) {
            // Do nothing
        }

        return array();
    }

Answer (score 5):

I've successfully imported some database entities by adding a `schema_filter` in the doctrine dbal config (`~/app/config/config.yml`)

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   %database_driver%
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        charset:  UTF8
        schema_filter: /^users_table/
```

`app/console doctrine:mapping:import --force MyBundle yml`

Then revert config.yml.

Answer (score 3):

I created a solution based on all comments that simplifies the code

on class
namespace Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver; 
DatabaseDriver.php

On line 277, change:

```
if (!$table->hasPrimaryKey()) {
      // comment this Throw exception
      // throw new MappingException(
      // “Table “ . $table->getName() . “ has no primary key.
      // Doctrine does not “.
      // “support reverse engineering from tables that don’t
      // have a primary key.”
      // );
} else {
     $pkColumns = $table->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns();
}
```

And, on line 488, add:

```
if( $table->hasPrimaryKey() ) //add this if to avoid fatalError
 return $table->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns();
```

To avoid any future problems, after mapping your database, return the settings to avoid any problems later.
Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for commenting on an old post but I bumped into the issue tonight and for me this solution was throwing an exception so I added `$pkColumns = array();` in the `if` condition and didn't need to add the part on line 488. Thank you very much.

Comment: Update for Doctrine 2.5.5 : first change is now on line 287 (function `reverseEngineerMappingFromDatabase()` ) and second change is on line 507 (function `getTablePrimaryKeys()` )

Answer (score 3):

Note that `--filter` in your command should be populated with the **Entity Class** name and not the **Table** name.  If the entity does not yet exists, the Entity Class name must compliment your table name.  So if your table is `user_table`, the filter value would be `UserTable`.

And then to work around that your DB has some tables that Doctrine cannot handle, you should whitelist the tables you do want allow Doctrine to manage.  You can do this in your config file like, so:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # ... 
        schema_filter: /^(users_table|emails)$/
```

alternatively you can specify this in your cli-config.php file.

```php
/** @var Doctrine\ORM\Configuration $config */
$config->setFilterSchemaAssetsExpression('/^(users_table|email)$/');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update the getTablePrimaryKeys function to:

```
private function getTablePrimaryKeys(Table $table)
{
    try {       
        $primaryKeyColumns = ($this->tables[$table->getName()]->hasPrimaryKey())?$this->tables[$table->getName()]->getPrimaryKey()->getColumns():array();
    } catch(SchemaException $e) {
        $primaryKeyColumns = array();
    }

    return array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the DatabaseDriver.php file reverseEngineerMappingFromDatabase function you can change

```
throw new MappingException("Table " . $table->getName() . " has no primary key. Doctrine does not "."support reverse engineering from tables that don't have a primary key.");
```

with

```
if(! $table->hasColumn('id')){
   $table->addColumn('id', 'integer', array('autoincrement' => true));
}
   $table->setPrimaryKey(array('id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try at least temporary change your doctrine config

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!table1|table2)~
```

And run:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert --force --from-database --filter="CamelCasedTableName" --namespace="App\Entity\\" annotation   .
```

Spent a lot of hours finding this solution.
Stange but upper answer by Courtney Miles didn't work for me. And this one works fine at least on symfony 4.4

Answer (score -1):

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/NameBundle/Resources/doctrine/metadata/orm

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import NameBundle yml

php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities NameBundle
```