# Doctrine Exclude Tables from entity generation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a database that I want to create entities only for the tables with ax_ appended onto the front of it.

I have search everywhere are cant find any explanations.

php app/console doctrine:mapping:import  --force AxxessORMBundle yml

This is the command I am using to create my entities

Comment: I assume you are creating tables using MySQL first and then importing? I know it's probably not ideal but have you tried it the other way and using http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables

Comment: Its an existing database

Comment: I have tried most things i the symfony documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will filter out the ax_ tables

schema_filter: ~^(?!ax_)~

I am however wanting to only use the ax_ tables

Comment: Then use `schema_filter: ~^ax_~`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for [ImportMappingDoctrineCommand](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineBundle/blob/master/Command/ImportMappingDoctrineCommand.php) there is a filter option

```
->addOption(
    'filter', 
    null, 
    InputOption::VALUE_REQUIRED | InputOption::VALUE_IS_ARRAY, 
    'A string pattern used to match entities that should be mapped.'
)
```

which I think you would be able to add your `ax_`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7997807/1791606) (paraphrased) says to convert and then import like so..

Convert

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml
    ./src/Axxess/ORMBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm 
    --from-database --force
```

Import

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import AxxessORMBundle yml --filter="ax_"
```

Comment: I'm so sorry ! I miss click and without realizing made a downvote ! I've noted it just now. If you want to I can remove it but you have to edit the answer because it doesn't allow  me to take it back.