# doctrine:generate:entities does not create all the properties

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

Mysql 5.6 
Doctrine 2.5

I created a table with 19 columns and ran

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle
```

As described here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html

Which created the entitity class and repository class but only created the `id` column. Also I notice there is no meta info such as autonumber for the id...I also tried with `-vvv` but it runs without error.

```
    namespace Test\CoreBundle\Entity;

/**
 * TestEvent
 */
class TestEvent
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Why did it not create the other 18 properties?

Comment: Please add the code for the mapping file that you generated

Comment: Hmm... there is no doctrine folder in `src/Test/CoreBundle/Resources/config`

Comment: What happens when you run the mapping import command?

Comment: [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]  "Table SELECT * from temp_update_table has no primary key." There is no table with that name.

Comment: You can refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15766666/1078488) for tables without a PK, but it's much easier to just remove it if you're able to. Make sure you have a proper db backup before venturing into this