# FOSUserBundle doctrine:mapping:import error

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am using FOSUserBundle. Everything was fine but I had to add column to database. During the import, my User.php class generated once again but it doesn't extend BaseUser class. Is there any way to do mapping:import without change full of User.php class?

User.php class is the class generated during the FOS installation.

Comment: for simple column changes why dont you just code it up manually? its extremely simple

Comment: It is during every import of database, even when the changes don't affect User class

Answer (score 0):

Try [`schema_filter`](https://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/generating_migrations.html#ignoring-custom-tables) in doctrine dbal options.

- [DoctrineMigrationsBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html)
- [Examples of usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547319/importing-tables-from-external-database-in-symfony2-with-doctrine)